# Determining the spatial orientation of a fault given ground acceleration magnitude in different directions

Tags: geophysics, seismology, tectonics

Accelerographs measure ground acceleration in three different components of motion: east-west, north-south, and vertically (up-down). I know that fault orientation is important here, so let's say we are dealing with a thrust fault. If an accelerograph shows greater ground acceleration in the north-south direction (greater than east-west ground acceleration), then could one assume that the fault which caused an earthquake is spatially oriented with north-south or east-west attitude?